# RabbitMQ php error Socket connection timed out

Tags: php, rabbitmq, php-amqplib

I'm getting socket connection timed out error. Due to the limited posts on php-amqplib. Can't figure it out.

**Note:** I'm trying to catch that error and reconnect on it. But can't figure out how to do it in php. something on the lines _onError of nodejs would help.

I'm getting the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPTimeoutException' with message 'Error sending data. Socket connection timed out' in /home/users/yagneshm/rabbitmq-php/vendor/videlalvaro/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php:194        

Stack trace:
        #0 /home/users/yagneshm/rabbitmq-php/vendor/videlalvaro/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AbstractConnection.php(336): PhpAmqpLib\Wire\IO\StreamIO->write('\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\r\x00<\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x04...')
        #1 /home/users/yagneshm/rabbitmq-php/vendor/videlalvaro/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AbstractConnection.php(377): PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection->write('\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\r\x00<\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x04...')
        #2 /home/users/yagneshm/rabbitmq-php/vendor/videlalvaro/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Channel/AMQPChannel.php(1102): PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection->send_content(1, 60, 0, 15, '\xB9\x80\x10application/...', 'test no. 998539', Object(PhpAmqpLib\Wire\AMQPWriter))
        #3 /home/users/yagneshm/rabbitmq-php/src/rmq.php(144): PhpAmqpLib\Channel\AMQ in /home/users/yagneshm/rabbitmq-php/vendor/videlalvaro/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php on line 194
```

I'm using the following connect function:

```
public function connect() 
    {
        try 
        {
            $this->connection = new AMQPStreamConnection($this->HOST, $this->PORT, $this->USER, $this->PASS, $this->VHOST, ['read_write_timeout' => 2 * $this->HEARTBEAT,'heartbeat'=> $this->HEARTBEAT]);
            $this->channel = $this->connection->channel();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "log error";    
        }
    }
```

And the following send message:

```
public function send($queue, $message, $params)
{
    try
    {
         $message = new AMQPMessage( $message, array( 'content_type' =>$contentType,
                                                      'delivery_mode' => $Persistent,
                                                      'expiration' => $Expiration,
                                                      'priority' => $Priority,
                                                      'message_id' => $messageId ));
          $this->channel->basic_publish($message, $exchangeName, $queue);            

     } catch (Exception $e) 
     {
            echo "log error";
     }
 }
```

Comment: Can you post the server logs?